# Why is there no implicit conversion sequence from int to vector<double>?

Tags: c++, c++11, implicit-conversion, explicit-constructor

Regarding

```
vector<double> v2 = 9; //error: no conversion from int to vector
```

Is there no implicit conversion sequence of the copy-initialization from

```
int
```

to

```
vector<double>
```

because

```
std::vector<double>(int)
```

is explicit?

Would it have been possible to have had a type conversion of type *floating-integral* conversion in the case of it not having been declared explicit?

Answer (score 3):

It would be ambiguous and semantically unconventional if you expected

```
vector<double> v2 = 9;
```

to be equivalent to

```
vector<double> v2( 9 ) ;
```

The latter does not assign a value of 9 to `v2`, the parameter is not an initialiser, rather it sets the length of the vector with initialised values determined by the default constructor of the type.  To create a vector with a *single* initial value 9 would require:

```
vector<double> v2( 1, 9 ) ;
```

or

```
std::vector<double> v2 { 9 } ;
```

Initialisation with `=` should conventionally have similar semantics to assignment, and in that case `v2 = 9` would be equally semantically ambiguous, or at least syntactically inconsistent.  Just as you cannot assign a single value to an array without an index, you should not expect to assign one to a vector.  Of course such a thing could have been defined, but would be confusing semantically.

Comment: For initialization it is also possible to write `std::vector<double> v2 = {9};`.